What's gonna be the physics behind building 'futuristic' airplanes? Use physics formulas or even theories to answer this question
After thinking about these 'futuristic' airplanes, I wonder if there's any special physics theory or law behind them. I wonder how faster they can be, persevere more and fulfill the aviation's lover wish. I would like it if someone helps me with any idea on how these 'futuristic' planes work according to Physics or even their design.

There are many possible answers to your question, so I'll give a try.
New and future aircraft are defined by the technologies that go into them.
Developing a new aircraft is very expensive, failure may risk the entire company, so we typically only take on new aircraft design when the technologies have advanced enough to make the new aircraft sufficiently better than the current ones.
Some technologies are relatively mature, so advances are slow and steady.  Others are in their early days, so we might expect breakthrough and dramatic advances.
Propulsion technologies are one of the most important to enable new generations of aircraft.  We can expect that turbofan engines will continue to get more powerful and fuel efficient -- but turbofans are very mature, so progress here will be slow.  The adoption of biofuel and sustainable fuel is one area of likely progress.  We may also shift to hydrogen as a primary fuel.
Hybrid and battery electric aircraft are an exciting new area.  Battery technology has a long way to go for most aviation missions.  Electrification opens the opportunity for a lot of design changes.  It also opens the opportunity for missions that can not be done with liquid fuel.
Other propulsion advances include high speed -- ramjet and scramjet technologies that may enable more practical supersonic and hypersonic flight.
Material technologies -- better metals, composites, and manufacturing processes.  These can enable lighter and more efficient aircraft.  They also can reduce the required maintenance on an aircraft and extend the service life by reducing the effects of fatigue and corrosion.
Aerodynamic technologies -- passive and active laminar flow, boundary layer ingestion engines, active flow control, etc.  All enable more efficient aircraft.
Autonomy -- increasing automation in the cockpit reduces pilot workload and increases safety.  Eventually this will lead to un-piloted aircraft acting autonomously.  Autonomous aircraft can do many potential missions more economically than piloted aircraft.
I'll let you continue this exercise -- think about the technology advance and then think about what it would do for aircraft design.

Why the downvote?  At least add a comment.

I think it's because opinion-based questions/answers are off-topic here

OT questions should not get answers

Note the question was after new physics, which I would have interpreted as constraining things to what is in the aerodynamics section, or possibly exotic engines.

@GremlinWranger Fair point.  I agree, after re-reading the question after my answer, there are things that could have made it a better fit.  However, (with the exception of autonomy) the examples listed often have the technologies originate in the physics.  You could argue that composites obey different physics than metals.  The physics isn't different at the level of conservation of mass, energy, and momentum -- but it is different in the details of how systems behave (turbine vs. scramjet) (batteries vs. liquid fuel) and in how we model systems (composite vs. metal).
